# Why index is showing wrong in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I was writing a program to find out the index number of a given value of 'o' in a string="Hello World". I have done it using three ways, first is using the index(), second is using the for loop with a counter variable, third is using the for loop with enumerate() function.

I have a problem with the counter variable. Hence, there are two 'o' in "Hello World" first is at the 4th index and the second is at the 7th index. but my counter variable is showing me 4 and 6 as the output. But the enumerate() is showing me 4 and 7 as the output. I want to know what is wrong with my counter variable.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
val = 'Hello World'
counter = 0
print("Index of 'o' Using Index Function: ", val.index('o', 5))
print('---------------------------------------')

for i in val:
    if i == 'o':
        print(i, counter)
              #I don't want to use break here because I want to print all the index of 'o'
    else:
        counter += 1
print("------------------")

for i, var in enumerate(val):
    print(i, var)
```

Here Is the Output

```
Index of 'o' Using Index Function:  7
---------------------------------------
o 4
o 6
------------------
0 H
1 e
2 l
3 l
4 o
5  
6 W
7 o
8 r
9 l
10 d
```

Comment: Should increment the `counter` regardless of the match.

Comment: Would you please Explain it a bit more, actually I am beginner.

Comment: You are doing `counter += 1` only when `i != "o"` i.e., in the `else` part; but `counter` must go up whether it hits `"o"` or not, right?

Comment: @KapilYadav remove the `else` block and let counter stay in the loop

Comment: Try changing `val = "ooooooooooo"` and run your code and see what `counter` has.

Comment: Oh, Thanks now my code is working as expected.. Thank you for letting me know about my mistake.

Comment: Your Answer was most satisfying but I don't know how to accept answers

Comment: Click on the tick button next to the answer

Comment: Its showing me you can accept the answer in one minute what does it mean?

Comment: Ok answer is accepted thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like error in the counting logic. first 'o' is not counted as counter increment was placed on else block. Try this,

```
for i in val:
    if i == 'o':
        print(i, counter)
    counter += 1
print("------------------")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the counter variable even when `o` is found.

```py
if i == 'o':
    print(i, counter)
counter += 1
```

Comment: I think you deleted your previous post as it was shown to me on my screen. Please use the edit button instead of delete. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
val = 'Hello World' 
counter = 0
print("Index of 'o' Using Index Function: ", val.index('o', 5))

print('---------------------------------------')

for i in val: 
    if i == 'o': 
        print(i, counter)
    counter += 1     

print("------------------")

for i, var in enumerate(val):
    print(i, var)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you using this code i have written

```py
def count(string, letter):
    assert letter in string, f"The letter {letter!r} is not in the string {string!r}"
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(string) if j == letter]
    

print(count('Hello World', "o"))
```

Which it prints out `[4, 7]` as you want.

it is called list-comprehension, it goes character by character and if the character equals to `letter`, then it adds it to the list.
equals to:

```py
counter = []
for i, j in enumerate(string):
    if j == letter:
        counter.append(i)
```

Comment: OP isn't sure what's going on with their own code, I don't think throwing another, unexplained  piece of code at them (with constructs they probably didn't see before) is going to be of much help

Comment: ```[i for i,j in enumerate(string) if j==letter]```. Use this

Comment: @Sujay ?, That's exactly what i did

Comment: I am telling to shorten it down to 1 line

Comment: Ah ok, i was actually about to doing that